# VBA - Spinbutton to change order in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I wonder if any of you can help me with one thing.

I have Listbox in userform that contains data,

**Example:**

Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4

I need a spin button where i can press Item2, then press up or down and it will be moved in the order i press the Spin button.

The code can either be linked to my Dynamic data connected to the Listbox, or directly to listbox somehow as long as i can move them around.

**Example:**

Item4, item2, Item3 item1 etc.

Thank you so much every contribution

Comment: I don't think there is a quick and easy solution for this. What you can do is to capture the most appropriate spin button event to see what the user wants. See your options here:   https://www.engram9.info/excel-2007-vba/spinbutton-events.html. Then you have to rearrange the content of the listbox accordingly. I'd rather employ two command buttons (up and down).

Comment: Thank you for the response :) i managed it